# ToDictionary for each element in a subarray with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following structure

```
class Parent
{
  public string id;
  public Child[] items;
}

class Child
{
  public string id;
}
```

```
[{ // ParentClass
  id: "parent_1",
  items: [
    { // ChildClass
      id: "child_1"
    },
    {
      id: "child_2"
    }
  ]
}, {
  id: "parent_2",
  items: [
    {
      id: "child_3"
    },
    {
      id: "child_4"
    }
  ]
}]
```

I want to create a dictionary so that i can find the parent of each subitem.

```
Dictionary
  child_1 => parent_1
  child_2 => parent_1
  child_3 => parent_2
  child_4 => parent_2
```

I am currently using nested for loop.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int,ParentClass>();
for(var parent in parents) {
  for(var child in parent.items) {
    dict.Add(child.Id, parent);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using linq?

Comment: See the Linq method [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary)

Comment: If your collection is plain json, then you can deserialize it directly to proper model

Comment: Try: `var dict = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => new { Parent = p, Child = i })).ToDictionary(i => i.Child.Id, i => i.Parent);`

Comment: @Vernou I know about todictionary, I wasn't sure how to use it for multiple items in the subarray. The lambda function in SelectMany was the missing piece

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It is not json, i was using that to show the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to link each child to its parent first:

```
parents.SelectMany(p => p.items.Select(c => new {p, c}))
       .ToDictionary(e => e.c.id, e.p);
```

Comment: this is it, i needed to introduce the anonymous object

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any class, I assume we will work with dynamics. If you have concrete class, code can be greatly simplified.

To deserialize and use the JSON, you can use following code:

```
// JArray class comes from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace
dynamic parsedArray = JArray.Parse("your json");
// Now you can access it's properties, example:
var firstItem = parsedArray[0];
var firstId = firstItem.id;
var firstItems = firstItem.items;
var firstSubitem = firstItems[0];
var firstSubitemId = firstSubitem.id;
```

To create dictionary, just use this code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
for (int i = 0; i < parsedArray.Count; i++)
{
    dict.Add(parsedArray[i].id.ToString(), parsedArray[i].items);
}
```